# Asynchronous Callbacks & Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, asynccallback

Hi I want to know more about how **Async Callbacks** works with **Sockets**.

Lets say from my **UI Thread** i call **BeginRead** method and pass in a callback named **Read** .  From my understanding, **BeginRead** spawns a new thread **(Thread A)** hence code execution in the UI Thread can still proceed. The callback **Read** is executed in **Thread A** right? It blocks at the **EndRead**.

Then does **Thread A** auto close itself once the callback ends?

In the assumption that **Thread A** closes itself once the callback is called:::

Does it mean its safe to call another **BeginRead** inside **Thread A** just before it ends? This **BeginRead** will spawn a **Thread B**. Will **Thread B** fail to execute or to correctly put it, will it terminate at some point because the calling thread which is **Thread A** was ended? Or are threads not dependant on the caller at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few misconceptions here. When you call `BeginRead` the callback that you specify will be called from within the internal thread pool of your application. There is typically no new thread started, though there might be one - it's up the the internal scheduler of .NET.

If you break your program in the debugger and go to the Threads view you should see a bunch of these threads named Worker threads. Typically all of them are sleeping and waiting for work. This is a much faster way than if `BeginRead` would spin up a thread each time you wanted to read. Instead it uses these workers that lay in the background, ready to go.

And when the callback is completed the worker thread goes back to the pool, ready for more action.

As for the rest of your questions:

- The callback should not block in `EndRead`. There will be no block in your application. The IO data will be available either buffered, in which case the callback will run almost instantly. Or the data will be available much later. In that case the callback will be executed only after the data has appeared. This is an important point because it means that while you're waiting for data there are *no* threads that wait for anything. The runtime takes case of the waiting and produces callbacks when data appears.
- Yes, its safe to call another `BeginRead` from your callback. There are no dependencies. In fact, it is a good way to do IO that way.
- Threads are never dependent on the caller. They are completely standalone and will die only when terminated naturally or when the process itself dies.

Comment: No! BeginRead does not need any thread at all. Not even a TP thread.

Comment: Non-blocking methods of Socket and NetworkStream classes use I/O completion ports as far as I know. Like @usr said, BeginRead shouldn't be using a ThreadPool thread.

Comment: I didn't say that begin read starts a thread, merely that the callback runs on a thread from the thread pool if you desire a callback. IO runs without threads

Answer (score 0):

`BeginRead` usually uses an operating system facility called async IO. The Windows Kernel does *not* require any thread to be associated with an IO operation.

I repeat: You can call `BeginRead` 1000 times and not a single more thread will start or be blocked.

The operating system queues the execution of your callback to the thread-pool, but only when the wait is over. `EndRead` will then complete immediately without waiting.

You can call `BeginRead` safely from your callback (usually after calling `EndRead`).